# Adding a JLabel to a JTextArea in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jtabbedpane

My code is below along with screenshots. I am trying to get a label above the JTextField. However, when the label displays, the buttons on the tab go away. My question is how do I get the label above the text area but with the buttons displaying as well?

Code with label:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TestApplication implements ActionListener {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(3000, 3000);
    frame.setTitle("RBA Test Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JLabel logLabel = new JLabel("Input / Output Log");


    JTextArea logbox = new JTextArea() {
    @Override
       public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(500, 500);
       };
    };

    logLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    logLabel.setText("Input / Output Log");

    logbox.add(logLabel);



    JButton initialize = new JButton("Initialize");

    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");

    JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");

    JButton shutdown = new JButton("Shut Down");

    JButton portsettings = new JButton("Port Settings");

    JButton online = new JButton("Go Online");

    JButton offline = new JButton("Go Offline");

    JButton status = new JButton("Status");

    JButton reboot = new JButton("Reboot");

    JButton account = new JButton("Account");

    JButton amount = new JButton("Amount");

    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");

    JButton approvordecl = new JButton("Approve / Decline");

    JButton test = new JButton("Test Button #1");

    JButton testing = new JButton("Test Button #2");

    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

    JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Check Box");



    JPanel newButtonPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
           public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
              return new Dimension(1000, 50);
           };
        };

    newButtonPanel.add(online);
    newButtonPanel.add(offline);
    newButtonPanel.add(status);
    newButtonPanel.add(reboot);
    newButtonPanel.add(account);
    newButtonPanel.add(amount);
    newButtonPanel.add(reset);
    newButtonPanel.add(approvordecl);


    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.add(button);
    testPanel.add(button2);
    testPanel.add(checkbox2);

    JPanel posPanel = new JPanel();
    posPanel.add(test);
    posPanel.add(testing);
    posPanel.add(checkbox);

    JPanel llpPanel = new JPanel();
    llpPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    llpPanel.add(newButtonPanel);
    llpPanel.add(new JScrollPane(logbox), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    llpPanel.add(logLabel);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(initialize);
    buttonPanel.add(connect);
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
    buttonPanel.add(shutdown);
    buttonPanel.add(portsettings);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("LLP", null, llpPanel, "Low Level Protocol");
    tabbedPane.addTab("POS",null, posPanel, "Point Of Sale");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Test", null, testPanel, "Test");

    JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tabsPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    frame.pack();



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






}
```

Screenshot with Label:

[image: label]

Code without label:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TestApplication implements ActionListener {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(3000, 3000);
    frame.setTitle("RBA Test Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JLabel logLabel = new JLabel("Input / Output Log");

    JTextArea logbox = new JTextArea() {
    @Override
       public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(500, 500);
       };
    };

    logLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
    logLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    logLabel.setText("Input / Output Log");

    logbox.add(logLabel);


    JButton initialize = new JButton("Initialize");

    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");

    JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");

    JButton shutdown = new JButton("Shut Down");


    JButton portsettings = new JButton("Port Settings");

    JButton online = new JButton("Go Online");

    JButton offline = new JButton("Go Offline");

    JButton status = new JButton("Status");

    JButton reboot = new JButton("Reboot");


    JButton account = new JButton("Account");

    JButton amount = new JButton("Amount");

    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");


    JButton approvordecl = new JButton("Approve / Decline");

    JButton test = new JButton("Test Button #1");

    JButton testing = new JButton("Test Button #2");

    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

    JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Check Box");



    JPanel newButtonPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
           public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
              return new Dimension(1000, 50);
           };
        };

    newButtonPanel.add(online);
    newButtonPanel.add(offline);
    newButtonPanel.add(status);
    newButtonPanel.add(reboot);
    newButtonPanel.add(account);
    newButtonPanel.add(amount);
    newButtonPanel.add(reset);
    newButtonPanel.add(approvordecl);


    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.add(button);
    testPanel.add(button2);
    testPanel.add(checkbox2);

    JPanel posPanel = new JPanel();
    posPanel.add(test);
    posPanel.add(testing);
    posPanel.add(checkbox);

    JPanel llpPanel = new JPanel();
    llpPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    llpPanel.add(newButtonPanel);
    llpPanel.add(new JScrollPane(logbox), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(initialize);
    buttonPanel.add(connect);
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
    buttonPanel.add(shutdown);
    buttonPanel.add(portsettings);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("LLP", null, llpPanel, "Low Level Protocol");
    tabbedPane.addTab("POS",null, posPanel, "Point Of Sale");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Test", null, testPanel, "Test");

    JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tabsPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    frame.pack();



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






}
```

Screenshot without Label:

[image: label]

Comment: does the label display on it too?

Comment: Wait, you're adding a JLabel to the JTextArea? Is this correct? If correct, this is highly unusual and not really recommended. Also, you're setting the preferred sizes of far too many things that it would be easy to see where this will cause components to bump into each other and cover each other.

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do. I am a beginner and don't really know what is usual and what is not. I am an intern and i making a test application so my "helper" i guess is what you would call it is going to help me clean up my code. can you give me any pointers as to what i can do? I am a little confused because the other guy said that it displays fine on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the components to `llpPanel` and in the order you expect to see them, from top to bottom:

```
llpPanel.add(newButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
llpPanel.add(logLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
llpPanel.add(new JScrollPane(logbox), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```